# Is there a reason why Peeves would not invade the common rooms or dormitories?

Tags: harry-potter, character-motivation

Being Peeves mischievous, why wouldn't he occasionally break into the houses' common rooms or dormitories to wreak havoc? He does not need a password insofar as he is ghost-like and can thus go through walls, neither is he ignorant of their location, since he has been in Hogwarts for a long time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You seem to make the assumption that ghosts/spirits can learn, no?  Is that actually established?

Comment: @DavidW Thank you for welcoming. I remember Sir Nicholas even sent letters to the Headless Knights and was declined, so from that I guess they could recall things that came to happen to them even in their "ghost-lifes", so to say. So I see no reason why Peeves would not be able to remember the location of the dorms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**He does.**

Chapter 9 of *Prisoner of Azkaban*:

> Harry woke extremely early the next morning; so early that it was still dark. For a moment he thought the roaring of the wind had woken him. Then he felt a cold breeze on the back of his neck and sat bolt upright- **Peeves the Poltergeist had been floating next to him**, blowing hard in his ear.
> "What did you do that for?" said Harry furiously. Peeves puffed out his cheeks, blew hard, and **zoomed backward out of the room**, cackling.
> Harry fumbled for his alarm clock and looked at it. It was half past four. Cursing Peeves, he rolled over and tried to get back to sleep, but it was very difficult, now that he was awake, to ignore the sounds of the thunder rumbling overhead, the pounding of the wind against the castle walls, and the distant creaking of the trees in the Forbidden Forest. In a few hours he would be out on the Quidditch field, battling through that gale. Finally, he gave up any thought of more sleep, got up, dressed, picked up his Nimbus Two Thousand, and **walked quietly out of the dormitory.**
> As Harry opened the door, something brushed against his leg. He bent down just in time to grab Crookshanks by the end of his bushy tail and drag him outside.

Peeves clearly goes out of the dormitory- straight into the common room.

Comment: Is Harry in the Gryffindor Common Room when this incident happens?

Comment: @Valorum- He's in the dormitory. I'll edit it in to the answer

Comment: How do you know that he didn't zoom backwards out of the room and out of the tower entirely?

Comment: @Valorum- I think that whatever barrier one would need to pass to get into the dormitory, he'll also need to pass to get into the common room (and I'll even think that the dormitories will have more protection. The fact that Peeves managed to get into the dormitory I think is proof he can also get into the common room. If there is any explanation for him not being able to get into the  common room in spite of entering the dormitory, I'd love to hear. This isn't a perfect answer but it makes sense.

Comment: This answer is a perfect example of what I lovingly refer to as ***"You're not wrong, but your source doesn't actually prove your assertion"***

Comment: @Valorum- yeah you're kinda right...

Comment: @Valorum is indeed quite right, but what I really meant was the same for dorms or common rooms. If he enters the dorms, it seems pretty hard to suppose that he couldn't enter the common room. I've edited the question anyway, and thanks, I did not remember this one occasion. Thank god Peeves wasn't more disruptive than that! ;)